# how to get selected option jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I know there's a "select" event but is not working.

This is my code:

```
$("#Asignacion_Movimiento_OrdenCompra").autocomplete(
        "/Asignaciones/ObtenerOrdenesCompra",
        {
            extraParams: { Serial: function () { return $("#Asignacion_Movimiento_Material").val(); } },
            delay: 200,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                alert(this.value + " - " + ui.item.value);
                ObtenerDatosAdicionales();
                return true;
            }
        }
    );
```

I also tried adding:

```
result: function (event, data, formatted) {
                alert(data);
                ObtenerDatosAdicionales();
                return true;
            }
```

But nothing happens...

How can I get the value of the selected item by the user?

Thx.

Answer (score -12, accepted):

Done!

I added the following to my $(document).ready function:

```
$('#autocompleteField').result(function (event, data, formatted) {
        alert(data);
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should have accepted @Josiah Ruddell's answer instead of posting the same...

Answer (score 28):

You are looking for the result. [See here for documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/result#handler).

Like so:

```
$("#Asignacion_Movimiento_OrdenCompra").autocomplete({
 /* your options here*/
}).result(function(event, data, formatted) { // result is a separate function
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: I added the result handler (see edit above) and nothing happens...

Comment: Looks like result is no longer a function. I think the replacement is select. `$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  select: function( event, ui ) {}
});`

Answer (score 16):

I know this thread is a bit old, but at http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=324203.0 I found a working example for select:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
var selectedObj = ui.item;
alert(selectedObj.value); }
```

Comment: Looks like your link is broken but the answer is perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @klerik: Yes, seems so, that's why I also posted the solution here :-)

Answer (score -1):

Get the selected option value from the jquery Autocomplete

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
source: availableTags,
select: function(event, ui) {
         //For better understanding kindly alert the below commented code
         alert(ui.toSource()); 
         var selectedObj = ui.item;
         alert(selectedObj.value);
    }
});
```